# TypeError: unique() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_counts'

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.x

I am trying to count unique values in an array by using these statements:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(temp, return_counts= True)
print np.asarray((unique, counts)).T
```

But I'm getting below error,

```
TypeError: unique() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_counts'
```

I even tried replacing `return_counts` with True in print statement, but the result is wrong. 
Here is what the result looks like,

```
temp:[[100, 100, 0], [100, 100, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
count matrix: 
[[  0   2]
[100   0]]
```

I want to count the number of unique values in array and expecting result like below,

```
result: [[100,4],[0,5]]
```

Is there any better way to count unique values?

Comment: can you please look into this. @NumesSanguis

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? return_counts was added in  `1.9.0`

Comment: The `return_counts` was introduced in numpy 1.9 (see [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)). So I suspect you are using an earlier numpy version.

Comment: My numpy version is '1.10.4'. @MSeifert

Comment: @AN_SH,  so `import numpy;numpy.__version__` gives you 1.10.4?

Comment: That's strange because I use numpy 1.10.4 an get a result: ``[[  0,   5], [100,   4]]``

Comment: @MSeifert, I used numpy.version.version, but the result is same. Yes the code works correctly, if I am running it on console and gives correct results. But when I code same in Editor window, it gives me error. Please note: I'm using arcgis tools. So I am getting output on arcgis tool, not on python console.

Comment: If there is an other way of counting unique values, it would be appreciated.

Comment: The source code for `np.unique` is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.10.1/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py#L96-L216). You could just copy the code into a self-made-function. :)

Comment: @MSeifert , I've tried it too, but its not working, as I have 2D array and I need the count of all unique values.

Comment: You should check the numpy version with the same tool ypu are having the problem.

Comment: There is nothing in the source that would permit using it as standalone... any specific errors?

Comment: Used below:

    a = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[4,5,6,7],[8,5,2,6]]

    print np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
(array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1], dtype=int64))
@MSeifert

Comment: But that's correct, you do have for example 2 `1` and 3 `2`s...

Comment: @MSeifert , Oh I total missed that. I am sorry. But it is still not working with tool, getting same error.

Comment: Just copy the complete numpy function I linked in your project and instead of calling `np.unique` call `unique` with the arguments.

Comment: @Goyo , Yes you are correct, the tool has version 1.7.1. but don't know how to update it.

Comment: @MSeifert , the tool doesn't know unique until I add numpy. again the tool is lower version.

Comment: Copy ([`C&P`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut,_copy,_and_paste)) the function source code into your source code and call that function instead of the numpy one.

Comment: @MSeifert , is there any way to count unique version in version lower than  1.7.1. As the tool, i am using is sensitive and will need research on to upgrade it. Till then I want it to work.

Comment: @MSeifert, I even updated the version in tool. But still the error is same. Its not able to recognize "return_counts"

Comment: i solved simply by `np.unique(mydict, True)`

Answer (score 0):

I made use of dictionary to count the unique values and and the logic is working great with the tool, I am using.

```
if temp[k][l] in dict_temp:
                    cnt = dict_temp.get(temp[k][l])
                    cnt =cnt+1
                    dict_temp.update({temp[k][l]:cnt})
else:
                    count = 0
                    count =count + 1
                    dict_temp.update({temp[k][l]:count})
```